RestClient: ErrorHandler is not getting executed
I use following call against my mock server which returns a 500.
restClient
            .post()
            .uri(URI)
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
            .body(file)
            .retrieve();


My RestClient is built as follows:
RestClient.builder()
            .baseUrl(getBaseUrl())
            .defaultHeaders(httpHeaders ->
                getDefaultHttpHeaders().forEach(httpHeaders::set))
            .requestInterceptor(userIdFunction())
            .requestInterceptor(addLogging())
            .defaultStatusHandler(HttpStatusCode::is5xxServerError,
                errorHandler())
            .build();

whereas
  private ErrorHandler errorHandler() {
        return (request, response) -> log.error("log something");
    }

However the lambda in the errorHandler() is never exectued.
Can someone explain this behavior and how to fix it to work as intended?
I also tried
public abstract RestClient.Builder defaultStatusHandler( org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler errorHandler)

and
onStatus()

The result is as above.

Found the issue!
I missed .toBodilessEntity() at the end of my post request.
